# getting error on recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
var summation = function(num) {
  if (num <= 0) {
    console.log("number should be greater than 0");
  } else {
    return (num + summation(num - 1));
  }
};
console.log(summation(5));
```

it gives me NaN error but i want summation of number.where am i making mistake?

Comment: @blex thanks, it works  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last iteration, you correctly check whether the input is `<= 0`, but then return nothing, which results in an implicit return value of `undefined`.

Adding `undefined` to a number results in `NaN`:

```js
console.log(1 + undefined); // NaN
```

To resolve this, return `0` if your cancellation condition has been hit:

```js
var summation = function(num) {
  if (num <= 0) {
    console.log("number should be greater than 0");
    return 0;
  } else {
    return (num + summation(num - 1));
  }
};
console.log(summation(5));
```

Comment: thanks it's working now and i also got my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var summation = function (num) {
  if(num <=0){
    console.log("number should be greater than 0");
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    return(num + summation(num-1));
  }
};
console.log(summation(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var summation = function (num) {
  if(num <=0){
  console.log("number should be greater than 0");
  return(0);
  }else{
  return(num + summation(num-1));
 }
};
console.log(summation(5));
```

there was no terminate statement for recursion earlier